# Returning query results in predefined order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Is it possible to do a `SELECT` statement with a predetermined order, ie. selecting IDs 7,2,5,9 and 8 **and returning them in that order**, based on nothing more than the ID field?

Both these statements return them in the same order:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id in (7,2,5,9,8)
```

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id in (8,2,5,9,7)
```

Comment: The title of this question is unclear.  Please edit it so that people scrolling past the question can understand it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I didn't think this was possible, but found a [blog entry here](http://www.handgestrickt.biz/item/21/) that seems to do the type of thing you're after:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id in (7,2,5,9,8) 
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id,"7,2,5,9,8");
```

will give different results to

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id in (7,2,5,9,8) 
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id,"8,2,5,9,7");
```

`FIND_IN_SET` returns the position of `id` in the second argument given to it, so for the first case above, `id` of 7 is at position 1 in the set, 2 at 2 and so on - mysql internally works out something like

```
id | FIND_IN_SET
---|-----------
7  | 1
2  | 2
5  | 3
```

then orders by the results of `FIND_IN_SET`.

Comment: Tested on v5 here, and it works well! The blog linked above mentions a more complicated set of queries where it may be even more useful

Comment: It can be, ordering by the results of find_in_set will use a filesort, so depending on your db schema it may not be a great option for your particular case.

Comment: I've been using this technique for ages and it works fine - only problem I have is records not in the list appear first... rather annoying.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(ID,7,2,4,5,8)
```

...but it's still ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Could you include a case expression that maps your IDs 7,2,5,... to the ordinals 1,2,3,... and then order by that expression?

Answer (score 0):

All ordering is done by the ORDER BY keywords, you can only however sort ascending and descending. If you are using a language such as PHP you can then sort them accordingly using some code but I do not believe it is possible with MySQL alone.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Oracle.  Can you do something similar in MySql?

```
SELECT ID_FIELD
FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE ID_FIELD IN(11,10,14,12,13)
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN ID_FIELD = 11 THEN 0
       WHEN ID_FIELD = 10 THEN 1
       WHEN ID_FIELD = 14 THEN 2
       WHEN ID_FIELD = 12 THEN 3
       WHEN ID_FIELD = 13 THEN 4
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a temp table with an autonumber field and insert into it in the desired order. Then sort on the new autonumber field.

Answer (score 0):

It's hacky (and probably slow), but you can get the effect with UNION ALL:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = 7
UNION ALL SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = 2
UNION ALL SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = 5
UNION ALL SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = 9
UNION ALL SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = 8;
```

**Edit:** Other people mentioned the find_in_set function which is documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

Answer (score 0):

Erm, not really. Closest you can get is probably:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (3, 2, 1, 4) ORDER BY id=4, id=1, id=2, id=3
```

But you probably don't want that :)

It's hard to give you any more specific advice without more information about what's in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You get answers fast around here, don't you…

The reason I'm asking this is that it's the only way I can think of to avoid sorting a complex multidimensional array. I'm not saying it would be difficult to sort, but if there were a simpler way to do it with straight sql, then why not.

Answer (score 0):

One Oracle solution is:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id in (7,2,5,9,8)
ORDER BY DECODE(id,7,1,2,2,5,3,9,4,8,5,6);
```

This assigns an order number to each ID.  Works OK for a small set of values.

Answer (score -1):

Best I can think of is adding a second Column orderColumn:

```
7 1
2 2
5 3
9 4 
8 5
```

And then just do a ORDER BY orderColumn