# WordPress query arguments set order statically

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to order my WordPress query by category ID but want to set the order statically.

below are the arguments that set the order:

```
'orderby' => 'ID',
'order' => 'ASC',
```

Is it possible to set the 'order' statically

like so:

```
'order' => '50,49,48,51',
```

I have tried using the post_in attribute but still am not seeing the order update:

```
$args = array(
             'post_type' => $custom_post_type,
             "$taxonomy" => $taxonomy_term->slug,
             'post_status' => 'publish',
         'post_in' => array(5,47,48,49,46,50),
         'orderby' => 'post_in', 
             'posts_per_page' => 9999
                                            );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function posts_orderby( $orderby ) {
  global $wpdb;
  $orderby  = 'FIND_IN_SET(ID, "50,49,48,51")';
  return $orderby;
}
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'posts_orderby');
```

Reading: [Returning query results in predefined order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134379/returning-query-results-in-predefined-order)
http://www.undolog.com/2012/03/13/wordpress-get_posts-e-orderby/

Answer (score 1):

go for this plugin : `"taxonomy-terms-order"`

[taxonomy-terms-order](http://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/)

thanks