# MySQL provide exact prespecified ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I execute the following query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    main_items
WHERE 
    group_id IN ('985ce7', 'fc154', 'f387cd', 'd3d27')
GROUP BY
    group_id 
ORDER BY                                   
    ('985ce7', 'fc154', 'f387cd', 'd3d27') # this is the line I'm referring to
```

Basically, I want the items to be ordered in the exact order I"m specifying above. How would I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134379/returning-query-results-in-predefined-order

Comment: I tried `ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(group_id, "'985ce7', 'fc154', 'f387cd', 'd3d27'")` and it gave me the same result as if leaving that off. What would be the correct syntax here?

Comment: All of the `find_in_set`s return 0 when I try the query on it's own.

Comment: Another approach, for completeness: do a full join to a lookup table which specifies an ordinal you can order by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(group_id, '985ce7', 'fc154', 'f387cd', 'd3d27')
```

or

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(group_id, '985ce7,fc154,f387cd,d3d27')
```

If the values of `group_id` contain commas then the first option becomes the only option.

Answer (score 1):

this has worked for me in the past:

```
ORDER BY FIELD('985ce7', 'fc154', 'f387cd', 'd3d27')
```